# Can't find Android App in Google play Store

Tags: android

i have my own app called Geoperks-rewards for you, the problem is i am not able to find my app from google play store for some handsets and even in tablet pc>Can anyone tell me what actually might be the reason behind this.I cannot specifically say for which models and OS versions, its appearing for random models.

Comment: in order to be sure the app is compatible with your device , open its website on the play store via a web browser (either on the problematic device or on your PC). then , see if the device is listed as one that can install it. after that, you might be able to decide what can be done.

Comment: The Google Play app only shows apps that can be installed on your device. The web version should list everything available, but maybe it is restricted by country. You could log into the Google Play developer console and check both the list of supported devices (on the APK page) and check the country settings.

Comment: So the common thing is Google Play app only shows apps that can be installed on your device right??But my app supports >=2.2 so i can find the app in one handset of 2.2 but i coudn't in other handset of 2.3.Why is that so??Both the handsets are of from same brand. I can even find it in 4.2 version but can't in tablet pcs..

Answer (score 0):

The App compatibility depends on many factors, i.e. screen sizes, OS version, device hardware support, some features added in app, etc... All this information is provided on Android Developer website by Google. You can go through the topic [Filters on Google Play](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html) and maybe revise the manifest.xml file of your app. You might get some idea why it is not compatible with several devices.